# test results summary in Axo cover Report generator

Tags: visual-studio, code-coverage, opencover, reportgenerator

I am using AxoCover code coverage tool for generating the code coverage report in visual studio. I wanted to include unit test results [pass\fail] in the unit test report summary. Is it possible?

I am using visual studio 2017 Professional.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqoBr.png)

Answer (score 1):

[ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator) only reads the coverage results of [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover). It does not process the tests results of MSTest/xUnit/nUnit.